# How to create Azure API Gateway Resource?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-api-management, azureportal

I want to create an API Gateway Resource in Azure. I got links on how to create API management instance but that doesn't talk about creating a gateway.

[Here is the link to create API Management Instance.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/get-started-create-service-instance)

Comment: Do you mean [Application Gateway](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/overview)?

Comment: @TomW No, I want to create a Azure API Gateway Resource.

Comment: There is no resource type called Azure API Gateway. Unless you mean [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.apimanagement/2021-01-01-preview/service/gateways/apis?tabs=bicep) child resource of an API Management instance, an 'API Gateway' in the general sense is an [architectural pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/microservices/design/gateway) with a number of implementations. Please specify what you mean.

Comment: I do not exactly mean resource but when we create API management instance, there should be a way to create an API gateway too. On more searching, I found this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-provision-self-hosted-gateway Since, there can only be managed and self-hosted gateways, this was the one I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you [Tom W](https://stackoverflow.com/users/313414/tom-w) and [Amber Bhanarkar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10097229/amber-bhanarkar). Posting your suggestions as an answer to help other community members.

**[Provisioning a gateway resource in your Azure API Management instance is a prerequisite for deploying a self-hosted gateway](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-provision-self-hosted-gateway).**

**Go to your API Management instance**

1. In the Azure portal, search for and select **API Management services**.
   [image]
2. On the API Management services page, select your API Management instance.
   [image]

**Provision a self-hosted gateway**

3. Select the **Gateways** from under **Deployment and infrastructure**.
4. Click + **Add**.
5. Enter the **Name** and **Region** of the gateway.
6. Optionally, enter a **Description** of the gateway resource.
7. Optionally, select + under **APIs** to associate one or more APIs with this gateway resource and click **Add**.

Now the gateway resource has been provisioned in your API Management instance. You can proceed to deploy the gateway.

You can refer to [Azure API Management and Application Gateway integration](https://medium.com/azure-architects/azure-api-management-and-application-gateway-integration-a31fde80f3db), [Integrate API Management in an internal virtual network with Application Gateway](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-integrate-internal-vnet-appgateway) and [Protect APIs with Application Gateway and API Management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/reference-architectures/apis/protect-apis)